# Tools for website/web application load testing?

Tags: sql-server, testing, web-applications, load-testing, cfml

Before going into production, our client demands actual numbers of **how many users our web application can handle**.

We have all kinds of features implemented including asset management (file uploads/downloads), documents import/export, various statistics, web-services etc.

I guess we need tool which could emulate users form submission because documents import/export as far as I noticed is the slowest part of an app because of parsing and generation.

**Which tool (or set of tools) could do this?**

Application details:

- XHTML/jQuery
- Coldfusion 8
- SQL Server 2008
- Windows Server 2008

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I like [jMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/) - free software and does the job quite well.

Few intro screencasts:

http://www.fosscasts.com/screencasts/3-Load-Testing-with-Apache-JMeter

http://vimeo.com/10164982

Comment: +1, good links. Will have to check that out!

Comment: +1 for JMeter. Easy and simple to use.

Answer (score 2):

[HPs Open Source HTTPerf](http://www.hpl.hp.com/research/linux/httperf/) I like. Just setup the URLS you want to test and let it rip. use a couple of machines to emulate load. You could even parse the output into a DB and do some number crunching.

Also, think about doing HTTPerf runs with profiling on the server side to see what lags and what doesnt. A nice touch is to let a user go on the app, and record all POST/GET requests and use them as a replay set for typical user interactions.

Also, if you are thinking about UX, use firebug or something to check JS imports are being done asynchronously instead of one-at-a-time. Have a ganders at [Stackoverflow question 310583/loading-javascript-dependencies-on-demand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/310583/loading-javascript-dependencies-on-demand)

Answer (score 2):

- http://loadimpact.com/
- [WebLoad: Professional and open
  source load testing](http://experts.na3.acrobat.com/p12246475/) from
  [CFMeetup](http://www.meetup.com/coldfusionmeetup/)

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio Ultimate edition has great load/stress testing tools, although the ultimate edition can be a bit expensive.

Answer (score 0):

m using Full version of JBlitz Professional 5.0 ..
it's very good

Answer (score 0):

There are few analytical performance tool out in market(not free) one i came through and works well is New Relic. If you are looking only to test the api then http://locust.io/ is good one and free too.