# Load JavaScript dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a web page and a canvas with Google Maps embedded in it. I am using jQuery on this site.

I want to load Google Maps API only if the user clicks on "Show me the map". Further, I want to take away the whole loading of the Google Maps from the header in order to improve my page performance.

So I need to load JavaScript dynamically. What JavaScript function I can use?

Comment: You may want to check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/310583/loading-javascript-dependencies-on-demand

Comment: @Igor Since he's using jQuery already, using `$.getScript` should remove the hassle.

Comment: @Arnaud Yes, you're probably right.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You may want to use [**jQuery.getScript**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/) which will help you load the Google Maps API javascript file when needed.

**Example:**

```
$.getScript('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry&sensor=true', function(data, textStatus){
   console.log(textStatus, data);
   // do whatever you want
});
```

Comment: Beware that the success callback is called once the script has been _loaded_, before it has been _executed_.

Answer (score 10):

Use the **Loading on Demand** Loading Strategy

### Loading on Demand

> The previous pattern loaded additional JavaScript unconditionally after page load, assuming
>   that the code will likely be needed. But can we do better and load only parts of
>   the code and only the parts that are really needed?
>   Imagine you have a sidebar on the page with different tabs. Clicking on a tab makes an
>   XHR request to get content, updates the tab content, and animates the update fading
>   the color. 
>   **And what if this is the only place on the page you need your XHR and animation
>   libraries, and what if the user never clicks on a tab?**
>   Enter the **load-on-demand** pattern. You can create a require() function or method that
>   takes a filename of a script to be loaded and a callback function to be executed when
>   the additional script is loaded.

The require() function can be used like so:

```
require("extra.js", function () {
   functionDefinedInExtraJS();
});
```

Let’s see how you can implement such a function. Requesting the additional script is
straightforward. You just follow the dynamic  element pattern. Figuring out
when the script is loaded is a little trickier due to the browser differences:

```
function require(file, callback) {
   var script = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0],
   newjs = document.createElement('script');

  // IE
  newjs.onreadystatechange = function () {
     if (newjs.readyState === 'loaded' || newjs.readyState === 'complete') {
        newjs.onreadystatechange = null;
        callback();
     }
  };
  // others
  newjs.onload = function () {
     callback();
  }; 
  newjs.src = file;
  script.parentNode.insertBefore(newjs, script);
}
```

*“JavaScript Patterns, by Stoyan Stefanov
(O’Reilly). Copyright 2010 Yahoo!, Inc., 9780596806750.”*

Comment: this is an absolute life-saver when trying to dynamically load local files from a local (file:///) context... thanks a bunch :)

Answer (score 4):

you would just generate the script tag via javascript and add it to the doc.

```
function AddScriptTag(src) {
    var node = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0] || document.body;
    if(node){
        var script = document.createElement("script");
        script.type="text/javascript";
        script.src=src
        node.appendChild(script);
    } else {
        document.write("<script src='"+src+"' type='text/javascript'></script>");
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that `document.getElementsByTagName` is cross-browser enough?

Comment: Yet it is, as per http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html#t12

Answer (score 0):

I think you're loking for this http://unixpapa.com/js/dyna.html

```
<input type="button" onclick="helper()" value="Helper">

   <script language="JavaScript">
   function helper()
   {
      var head= document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
      var script= document.createElement('script');
      script.type= 'text/javascript';
      script.src= 'your_script_url';
      head.appendChild(script);
   }
   </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the Tangim response, but after found that is more easy use jquery html() function. When we make ajax request to html file that have html+javascript we do the follow:

```
$.ajax({
    url:'file.html',
    success:function(data){
       $("#id_div").html(data); //Here automatically load script if html contain
    }
});
```