# loading javascript file accordingly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to load from different javascript (.js) file accordingly.
e.g. when button 1 click, then load 1.js, when other one click, then load the relevant .js file. (e.g. 2.js)

I've just know  would be the usual way to load a js file. is there any other way could achieve that with the same effect but provide the possibilities to load different .js accordingly?? any jquery function would also do that?

Reagrds

Comment: An older question might help - 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9037082/how-to-load-javascript-code-to-an-html-file-at-runtime

Comment: check if this solves your problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/310583/loading-javascript-dependencies-on-demand

Answer (score 1):

You could try the following:

```
$(".button").click(function(){
 $("html head").append("<script src='script.js'></script>");
});
```

I'm just thinking that the downside of this would be that javascript files normally load with the page. So the loaded script must be workable after appended to the html doc?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [$.getSCript](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/)

```
$.getScript( "ajax/test.js", function( ) {
  // callback called after js loaded successfully
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this

```
$('#btn1').click(function(){
    $('<script />', { type : 'text/javascript', src : 'yourscript1.js'}).appendTo('head');
});
$('#btn2').click(function(){
    $('<script />', { type : 'text/javascript', src : 'yourscript2.js'}).appendTo('head');
});
```

This would add script file based on your button clicked.